# In Flash Builder 4.5 for Mac, how can I use xdebug as my PHP debugger (instead of Zend Debugger)?

Tags: mac, php, debug, flexbuilder

Currently, under Preferences>PHP>Debug>Installed Debugger, only Zend Debugger is shown, and there is no way to add xdebug, even though I have verified that it is active using phpinfo().

Does anyone know a way to add xdebug (probably via "Install New Software", but any method will be appreciated)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have it installed now, but if I remember well, on the beta I renamed all Eclipse zend debugger plugins. I think they were two or three. I have just added a ".no" at the end of the name changing their extensions.

I then restarted FB for PHP, and in the options I was finaly able to insert my XDebug parameters. I hope it still works like that with the release version.

The files to rename are:

```
com.zend.php.debug.ui_8.0.0.v20110117-2133.jar
com.zend.php.debug.core_8.0.0.v20110331-1830.jar
```

I simply renamed them to:

```
com.zend.php.debug.ui_8.0.0.v20110117-2133.jar.no
com.zend.php.debug.core_8.0.0.v20110331-1830.jar.no
```

After that, xdebug magically shows up in the installed debuggers list.